# kodak easyshare & windows 7

Tags: windows-7

can't get kodak easyshare to download to windows 7, any ideas

Answer (score 2):

I always avoid installing software that comes with hardware devices if I can. If your camera supports [Picture Transfer Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_Transfer_Protocol) over USB (and most do), just plug it in and Windows should pop up a dialog for downloading the pictures.

Comment: so what would you suggest I use for organising photos?

Comment: Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 1):

did you download the **[latest version](http://wwwuk.kodak.com/global/mul/service/downloads/DownloadLookup.jhtml?pq-path=4509&product=EKN026079&operatingSystem=windows_7)** (8.1, release date 22-September-2009) from the KODAK website?

older versions may not be compatible with Windows 7.